# Can a disabled Windows Form be activated?

Tags: winforms

I have a strange problem that disabling a Form reacts different in two different release version of our application.

In the most recent one, when disabling a Form, you cannot give it focus. When I click on a disabled form, you can hear a bell sound. No OnActivated event is triggered.

In a previous version however, disabling the same Form doesn't prevent me from giving it focus (from selecting it). As a result, the OnActivated event is triggered.

First of all, what should be normal behavior? I am not doing anything in code to prevent a Form from being activated or getting focus, so I guess the Windows Form framework executes some logic when a Form is disabled.

Second, what could cause the difference?

Comment: It might be a subtle difference in version - OS version/patch level, .NET framework version/patch level... is this happening with the exact same versions ?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same machine, my development machine. There are some differences between the two versions of the application, but none that could explain the difference...

Comment: This has never been different.  The dingaling and the blinking is implemented in Windows, not Winforms.  The underlying native winapi call is EnableWindow().  The simplest explanation for the "previous version" behavior is that the window wasn't disabled, for whatever reason.

Comment: Hans: Can you point me to a msdn/windows article were it's noted that this is normal behavior? I'll have a closer look at our 'previous version' on what's different. I'm actually doing the same to disable the Form in the previous version but maybe some other logic is doing some extra stuff...